# What is wrong with this While or Loop?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get a user (with random user number) list from an Api.

I'm trying:
If the "code" (in Json) is 404, repeat function till won't return that code.

```
function getUser() {
$n1 = 1;
$n2 = 20000;
$api = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://example.com/api/user/'.rand($n1, $n2)), true);
$row = $api['code'];
while($row == '404') $api = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://example.com/api/user/'.rand($n1, $n2)), true);

return $api;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `$row` again.

Currently you keep testing the `$row` of your initial API call, not the latest one.

```
$row = $api['code'];
while( $row == '404' ) {
   $api = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://example.com/api/user/'.rand($n1, $n2)), true);
   $row = $api['code']; /* Assign the new value for $row  */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your `$row` variable should set per loop step.

```
$row = $api['code'];
while( $row == '404' ) {
   $api = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://example.com/api/user/'.rand($n1, $n2)), true);
   $row = $api['code'];//again set $row
}
```